# Creating an fts object in R with ftsa to functional data analysis of a time series

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis

I am using the ftsa-package for R and am trying to change a data frame of count data with 6 columns and dates for row names into an fts object.

I have count data for 6 categories of a multivariate time series. I have tried the following two functions fts(),is.fts(), and as.fts():

I have an xts object with the 6 columns of count data and dates

```
index(count.xts[1])
"2009-01-01"
dim(count.xts)
 730 6
dts = format(seq(from=index(count.xts[1]),length.out=dim(count.xts)[1],by="days"),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

# countData is the original data frame with the dates as row names and count data

```
count.fts1 = fts(index=as.Date(dts), data=as.matrix(countData))

count.fts2 = as.fts(data.frame(asofdate=dts,as.matrix(countData)))
```

When input either data object into ftsm() or plot() I get the following error:

```
 Error in 1:ncol(y$y) : argument of length 0
```

I ran the following diagnostics:

```
class(count.fts2)
[1] "fts" "zoo"

is.fts(count.fts2)
[1] FALSE
```

That doesn't really make any sense does it? It's a member of class fts but is NOT an fts object.

Just for good measure I did the following:

```
class(fts(index=as.Date(rownames(countData)),data=as.matrix(countData)))
[1] "fts" "zoo"

is.fts(fts(index=as.Date(rownames(new.count)),data=as.matrix(new.count)))
[1] FALSE
```

I am not sure what else to do at this point. Any advice you can give I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.